# Валидация модели при определенном условии yii2

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Я хочу осуществлять проверку поля на уникальность, только при его наличии, как мне в rules задать это условие? Делаю вот так:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       ['checked_box', 'unique',
           'on' => 'Только при наличии этого поля в модели'
       ],
    ];
}
```

Как мне записать такое простое условие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию если поле пустое то данное правило не применяется ([skipOnEmpty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$skipOnEmpty-detail)), другой вопрос как он проверяет, пустое данное поле или нет. Вы можете переопределить метод проверки значения на пустоту - [isEmpty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$isEmpty-detail), и посмотреть [проверку по умолчанию](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/Validator.php#L372)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       [
        'checked_box',
        'unique',
        'isEmpty'=>function($value){ return isset($value); },
        'on' => 'Только при наличии этого поля в модели'
       ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: спасибо, завтра попробую